# how can I change logitech c922 from 30fps at 1080p to 60fps at 720p on linux?

Tags: logitech

I want to set the defautl resolution to 720p to get 60fps video. I have been trying to use v4l2 to change its resolution but still am not able to get 60fps output video, it is stuck at its default 30fps I was wondering how I could change the default to 60fps at 720p.

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is not directly related to programming and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Well actually I am trying to process a video using opencv and I want the video to be of 60fps